# What is the best way to go about referencing multiple tables using slick 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.2, slick, play-slick, slick-2.0

I have these tables: USERS, USER_ROLES, ROLES, PERMISSIONS, ROLE_PERMISSIONS

I am implementing the:

```
AssignedRoles (M): returns the set of roles assigned to a given user;
```

So, if I was going to write the query for this function it would like something like this:

```
SELECT role_id FROM USER_ROLES WHERE user_id = 'M'
```

where M is the given user id, then I would look up each role by their id and return the Role object, or I would use a join, but that is not relevant here.

so where is what my UserRole model looks like:

```
case class UserRole(id:Long, userID:Long, roleID:Long)
object UserRoles {
  class UserRoles(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRole](tag, "USER_ROLES") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def userID = column[Long]("USER_ID")
    def roleID = column[Long]("ROLE_ID")

    def user = foreignKey("USER_ID", userID, TableQuery[Users])(_.id)
    def role = foreignKey("ROLE_ID", roleID, TableQuery[Roles])(_.id)

    def * = (id, userID, roleID) <> (UserRole.tupled, UserRole.unapply)
  }
  def retrieveRoles(userID:Long) : List[Role] = {
    DB.withSession { implicit session =>
      userRoles.filter(_.userID === userID).list
    }
  }
```

As expected retrieveRoles returns a list of UserRoles, but I want a list of Roles, so I woulds have to write another query that will take UserRole.roleID and find it in the roles table for each of UserRole that is returned. That is a lot of queries and I feel like there is a way that will to do this in one query. Any help from the Slick experts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userRoles.filter(_.userID === userID).flatMap(_.role)
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure on what that does, but here is the error that is giving me: `type mismatch; found : scala.slick.lifted.Query[models.Roles.Roles,models.Role] required: List[models.Role]`

Comment: well, call `.list` on it :).  Query is an object representing a not yet executed query.